# Remake a storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode6, uistoryboard

I started developing my app by unchecking the auto-layout at first(I didn't know how to use it) But once I finished it, I had to use auto-layout and its not in the best condition. Can I create a new storyboard with auto-layout feature checked, in the same project and copy the everything in the existing Storyboard to it?

Comment: yes you can.....or else you can check the auto layout in existing project

Answer (score 0):

Check the auto layout in existing project and then if you face any problem then ask here , If you want learn more about auto layouts then read the book `iOS Auto Layout Demystified, 2nd Edition`

Comment: I did check it and did something very stupid on it..i added so many size constraints(tried trial and error)now it simply looks weird in iphone 4s screen...

Comment: My app is exclusively for iphones in portrait mode.. If i remove all the constraints, will it work fine?

Comment: then simply remove all constraints and set them again or you can use `"cmd+z"` to get back to previous set constraints if xcode is not closed since changes made

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.Create a storyboard with autolayout clicked.Then go to the old storyboard,copy all the views using ***cmd+C*** and paste it in the new storyboard.
if you are new to autolayout use atutorial to start with [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-auto-layout-in-xcode-5--cms-21016](http://link1) and [http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2](http://link2)  may help

Answer (score 0):

Simply check 'Use Auto Layout' in 'File Inspector'. Either first copy your ViewController, then delete it and then paste it. Or you may just copy your View and paste it on any ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just create a new storyboard. If you are working in iOS 8.0 or greater SDK then it will automatically create the storyboard with auto layout property.

Steps to add new storyboard:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

I named it as New.Storyboard.

If you go to the file Inspector now, you will see, the auto layout and size class are checked in.

Drag and drop a View Controller in this New.Stroyboard.
Now, just to who steps, I added some stuffs in the main.storyboard(the one without the auto layout feature).

[image]

No, select the view under the View Controller under your Main.StoryBoard(where you added your desired views) and do "cmd+c" to copy all the items. then go to the New.Storyboard and again select the view under your View Controller and hit "cmd+v" to paste. It should look something like this-

[image]

Now set the constrains to make it look like your main.Storyboard's view controller.

Auto constrain can be quite daunting the first time and there are many ways to do same thing. So, make sure when you learn any technique, you also try to understand why you are setting that constrain that particular way. 
Try this tutorial. It explains you how you should start planning about setting up the constrains.

http://mobileoop.com/auto-layout-advanced-techniques-for-ios-8-and-7-using-xcode-6-on-storyboard

Besides, for beginners appcoda auto-layout is quite friendly. Try this-
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/